# Static member in a template class

Tags: c++, templates, static

I have a templated class and a static member of it, which is of type map.
I can't seem to figure out how to use that member. I have tried a few different variations but this is where it began.
I get an error in the definition of function size() :

```
undefined reference to `A<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::my_map_'    




#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

typedef map<string, int> si_map_t;

template<class T>
class A {
public:
    static map<T, int> my_map_;
    static void add(T key, int value) {
        my_map_.insert(std::pair<T, int>(key, value));
    }
    static size_t size() {
        return my_map_.size();
    }
};

template<>
si_map_t A<string>::my_map_;



int main() {
    A<string>::my_map_;
    size_t count = A<string>::size();
    cout << count << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *really* want to use explicit specialization of a class template member note that such notation

```
template <>
si_map_t A<string>::my_map_;
```

means only a *declaration* of a specialization. It is strange but it is true.

Use the following syntax to *define* a member specialization:

```
template <>
si_map_t A<string>::my_map_ = si_map_t();
```

Or the following C++11 syntax:

```
template <>
si_map_t A<string>::my_map_ = {};
```

or

```
template <>
si_map_t A<string>::my_map_{};
```

Answer (score 1):

I *think* this is what you're trying to do:

```
template<typename T>
using si_map_t = std::map<T, int>;

template<class T>
class A {
public:
    static si_map_t<T> my_map_;
    static void add(T key, int value) {
        my_map_.insert(std::pair<T, int>(key, value));
    }
    static size_t size() {
        return my_map_.size();
    }
};

template<typename T>
si_map_t<T> A<T>::my_map_;

int main()
{
    size_t count = A<string>::size();
    cout << count << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
0
```

Comment: Thanks. This does solve the problem. Sorry the problem looks a little contrived, I was just trying to abstract out the business logic.